# 10-contact FPC socket has 12 PCB terminals

Tags: connector, fpc, ffc

I have to place an FPC socket on my PCB. I selected 0.5 pitch and 10 contacts connector. Everyone has 12 PCB terminals instead of 10.

[image]

I am confused, what are those two extra pins for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To hold the connector in place. They are "anchors", though various companies call them with different names.

[image: Anchors]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, so i don't have to wire them in my design?

Comment: No, you don't. They are just pads.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Don't forget to do your part: voting and accepting.

Comment: To be clear to the OP about connecting them in the schematic: there is really nothing to connect. There is no electrical connection from extra pads to the FPC; they exist only to provide a solid mechanical connection to the PCB.

Comment: Connecting them to groundplane with vias can increase the strength of the pad to prevent it from being lifted off the PCB.